# guide non chrome users to install chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Does anyone know of a JS script to guide non chrome users to install chrome?

I can probably figure out how to do this myself but I am a big fan of not reinventing the wheel.

Im looking for something like this [image]

Comment: What do you mean? Some text and a link to the download page would "guide" them.

Comment: Many web apps do this.  They display a message that the current bowser does not work well with the app and refers them to a browser that is supported (like chrome)

Comment: why would you leave a site that did that.  Pandora does it

Comment: yes this would be true for mobile developement especially if you are using new features like Webgl and need chrome specificaly, check my answerr if that helps

Comment: Ahh my apologies, I assumed that you meant directly guide them towards installing Chrome. [Browser-Update](http://browser-update.org/) may be what you're looking for.

Comment: If you really mean feature detection - [use feature detection](http://modernizr.com/). Being warned to install a different browser or worse blocked is typically just annoying - especially if the user's browser _has_ whatever feature it is the site depends on. Alternatively, look into [things](http://www.browser-update.org/) [like](http://nmsdvid.com/iealert/) [this](http://lithium.ddns.info/~shanq/bitsnbytes/obw_en.html).

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
window.open("http://www.chrome.com");
```

I hope you don't mind my sarcasm.

Answer (score 1):

Okay here

```
var checkIsRunningChrome = window.chrome;
if(!checkIsRunningChrome)
{
    alert("It appears that you are not running on chrome, please install it");
    window.open("http://www.chrome.com");
}
```